# How to add two Auto-Renewable subscription for one application in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, auto-renewing

I am new to using iOS In-App Purchases. I want to add two subscriptions:
one is for 1 month and the second is for 3 months.

If i add different product id for same application (different subscriptions), will that work?

Comment: What happens when you try? Do you get an error back?

Comment: @AdamB i not get any error but now i set it thank you but now i want to test it mean inapt purchase for this please give me any resource. i added my user in to sand box now which step is required?

Comment: Please post a new question if you are stuck at a specific point, with the information on what you have done so far.

Comment: @Ashish: can you please post your code for autorenewable in app purchase? Please. I have done from this link https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit but, the I don't know how to check from code if user cancels or subscription is no longer available? Can you please help????